# Why a member method calling itself (recursively) doesn't enter in an endless loop?

Tags: python, function, class, recursion, member

I took this example from a blog, but I don't understand it.

```
>>> class Udict:
    def __init__(self, dict=None):
        self.data = {}
        if dict is not None: self.update(dict)
    def update(self, dict=None):
        self.data.update(dict)
        print(self.data)

>>> d = {1:'one', 2:'two'}
>>> g = Udict(d)
{1: 'two', 2: 'two'}
>>> g.data
{1: 'two', 2: 'two'}
>>> c.Udict()
{}
>>> c.update({3: 'three'})
{3: 'three'}
>>>
```

I expect a recursive call to obj.update() function until *'RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded'*

But no, the update() function reaches to `print(self.data)`

`self.data.update(dict)` is calling to itself method update(), so why it doesn't works like I expect?

Can anyone explain to me why a calling to function itself doesn't enter into an endless loop? The blog with the example doesn't explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.data != self.update

Here **self.data** is an **instance variable** which is a **dictionary object**. 
Dictionary object has **update method**. So when you call self.data.update(), it calls the method inside the dictionary:

```
>>> help(dict.update)
Help on method_descriptor:

update(...)
   D.update(E, **F) -> None.  Update D from dict/iterable E and F.
   If E has a .keys() method, does:     for k in E: D[k] = E[k]
   If E lacks .keys() method, does:     for (k, v) in E: D[k] = v
   In either case, this is followed by: for k in F: D[k] = F[k]
>>>
```

And self.update is an instance method of class Udict:

So lets re-write your code a little bit:

```
>>> class Udict:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.data = dict()
...     def update(self, dic=None):
...         if dic:
...             self.data.update(dic)
...         return self.data
...
>>> d = {1:'one', 2:'two'}
>>> g = Udict()
>>> g.update(d)
{1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
```

For better practice, please don't call any method from **init**(), please use **init**() only for initializing attributes, so in your case you can even initialised dic from the argument like:

```
>>> class Udict:
...     def __init__(self, dic=None):
...         self.data = dict()
...         if dic:
                self.data.update(dic)
```

Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @yopy, with your example I can understand it.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't calling itself recursively at all.

It doesn't call `self.update` within update: it calls the update method of the data dict, which is something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

When it calls `self.data.update`, it doesn't enter the same function. It is calling the `update` function of `self.data` which is simply a dict. If it calls something like `self.update` then recursion is happening, perhaps that's what you were thinking.

Comment: Thanks @YS-L ! Really, I'm very noob in OOP. I'd confused the class method with the object method that inherits of dict type.

Answer (score 1):

This does not call `Udict.update`, but [`dict.update`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) (not recursive):

```
self.data.update(dict)
```

Maybe you misunderstand with `self.update(dict)`.

BTW, don't use [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) as a variable name. It shadows builtin function [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict).